# Merging of Two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two php arrays:

```
$array_1 = array(1,6,7,8);
$array_2 = array(1,5,3,4,7,8);
```

I want output like this:

```
$array_3 = array(1,6,7,8,5,3,4);
```

It means that third array should contain all values of first array and then remaining all values which are not inside first array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
$array_1 = array(1,6,7,8);
$array_2 = array(1,5,3,4,7,8);
$array_3 = array_unique(array_merge($array_1,$array_2));
var_dump($array_3);
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(6)
  [2]=>
  int(7)
  [3]=>
  int(8)
  [5]=>
  int(5)
  [6]=>
  int(3)
  [7]=>
  int(4)
}
```